# How to manage mute/unmute on multiple videos using useRef like instagram reels in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, react-hooks, video-reactjs

I have created one component in which I am mapping videos and passing each video to one child component.
In child component managing video play/pause, mute/unmute using videoRef which I have bind in video tag.
And on scroll up/down moving to previous/next video.

I would have to develop one thing is that if I mute 1 video then all video should muted and unmute then all videos should be unmuted like instagram reels.

Now the issue is that if video is in pause mode and I mute one video then other videos are not getting muted. I am not getting any events on swipe to make new video mute.
If video is in play mode then everything is working fine.

So, I want to mute/unmute video in any mode like play or pause based on video swipe. Please help me out here.